# I want to achieve in laravel 5 the same thing as the cakephp of HttpSocket ()

Tags: php, cakephp, laravel

I want to achieve in laravel 5 the same thing as the cakephp of HttpSocket ().

Within your own site, and I want to get the result of the POST to other sites.

CakePhp source code:

```
$socket = new HttpSocket();
$url = 'http://other-site.com/pages/';

$option['login'] = array('id'=>'abc','pass'=>'xxxxxxx');
$option['data']['hasOne'] = array('startDate' => '2015-04-16', 'endDate' => '2015-04-17');
$list = unserialize($socket->post($url,$option));
```

In cakephp, can be achieved by the method described above, but does not know how to do in laravel 5.

Do not anyone understand here?

Comment: You should use external library, by requiring it in composer, e.g. http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest

Comment: @hiro if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

[Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) will help you.

1. Install it via Composer:

```shell
    composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

2. Alternative of your code using Guzzle:

```php
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->post(
        'http://other-site.com/pages/',
        [
            'login' => ['id' => 'abc', 'pass' => 'xxxxxxx'],
            'data' => ['hasOne' => ['startDate' => '2015-04-16', 'endDate' => '2015-04-17']]
        ]
    );

    if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
        $list = unserialize($response->getBody());
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
```